# Missing files after docker commit

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a docker image of my application, but when i start the container after building it, some files are missing.

Here are the steps i am taking to reproduce the issue:

1. Start a new docker:

   ```
   $ docker run -ti fedora /bin/sh
   ```
2. Download and extract my application bundle:

   ```
   $ curl -o /tmp/kornell-api-opt.tar.gz https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/dist-sa-east-1.craftware.com/kornell-api-opt.tar.gz

   $ tar zxf /tmp/kornell-api-opt.tar.gz --warning=no-unknown-keyword -C /opt
   ```
3. Count the files:

   ```
   $ find /opt/ | wc -l
   ```

   This returns me the count of **7739** files.
4. Save the image and start a new container:

   ```
   $ docker ps #copy the id  # (36f3cabf8ce6 this run)

   $ docker commit 36f3cabf8ce6 craftware/kornell

   $ docker run -ti craftware/kornell /bin/bash
   ```
5. Count the files again

   ```
   $ find /opt/ | wc -l
   ```

   This returns the count of **6254** files, instead of the **7739** i expected.

So, what could have happened to the missing files?

Docker version 1.0.0, build 63fe64c/1.0.0

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you are describing. Using a container from the committed image I find 7739 files. 

My version of docker:

    [vagrant@docker:~] $ docker version
    Client version: 1.0.1
    Client API version: 1.12
    Go version (client): go1.2.1
    Git commit (client): 990021a
    Server version: 1.0.1
    Server API version: 1.12
    Go version (server): go1.2.1
    Git commit (server): 990021a

Comment: Nice, i'll try your docker version to see if that can be it. I was running the default version on the latest Amazon Linux on EC2. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the number of files using `docker diff <container-ID>` before commit and see if it matches?